# If a simple function is nonnegative, why do the set on which the simple function is strictly positive have finite measure?

Tags: measure-theory

If a simple function is nonnegative, why do the set on which the simple function is strictly positive have finite measure?

I know it should be Sigma finite, but why is it finite?

This is from page 377 of Royden's real analysis. The book claimed this in the proof of (22).

Comment: Are you referring to the sentence “Since the simple function $\psi$ is integrable over $X$, the measurable set $X_0 = \{ x \in X \,|\, \psi(x) > 0\}$ has finite measure.”? In that case, the answer is given in the first half of the sentence. ;-)

Comment: Okay, this may sound very simple, but I still cannot quite get it. Isnt it all simple functions integrable?

Comment: Yes I am referring to this sentence. Thanks for typing it up

Comment: No, integrable means that $\int_X \phi$ is *finite*.

Comment: Okay how is it different from proposition 9 on page 368 though? In proposition 9, f is integrable, but we cannot say X is finite.

Comment: In that case, it's not a *simple* function. Just think of the case $X=\mathbf{R}$. There are plenty of functions which are positive on the whole real line, yet have finite area under the graph: $f(x)=1/(1+x^2)$, $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, etc. But that can't happen if you require that $f$ is simple (for example, if $f$ is piecewise constant: then $f$ can't decay at $\pm\infty$ unless it is identically zero outside some compact interval).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there was some assumption about the simple functions in the proof of that particular result. In general it is not true, as the constant function $f = 1$ is a nonnegative simple function.

Comment: That is what I am wondering. I don't see any assumption being made in the book, but I am new this stuff and it is hard for me to think out of the box. If you have there book handy, can you take a look?